# c++ - fstream and ofstream

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

What is the difference between:

```
fstream texfile;
textfile.open("Test.txt");
```

and

```
ofstream textfile;
textfile.open("Test.txt");
```

Are their function the same?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ofstream` only has methods for outputting, so for instance if you tried `textfile >> whatever` it would not compile. `fstream` can be used for input and output, although what will work depends on the flags you pass to the constructor / `open`.

```
std::string s;
std::ofstream ostream("file");
std::fstream stream("file", stream.out);

ostream >> s; // compiler error
stream >> s; // no compiler error, but operation will fail.
```

The comments have some more great points.

Comment: Also, `ofstream::open` defaults to openmode `ios_base::out`, and `fstream::open` defaults to `ios_base::in | ios_base::out`

Comment: Moreover, in the case of `std::fstream`, attempting to open the file will fail if the file does not exist. This is in contrast to `std::ofstream` which creates a file if one cannot be found. One would have to add the `std::ios_base::trunc` flag to the mask when calling the constructor or `open()` on an `std::fstream`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at their pages on cplusplus.com [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/).

`ofstream` inherits from `ostream`. `fstream` inherits from `iostream`, which inherits from both `istream` and `stream`. Generally `ofstream` only supports output operations (i.e. textfile << "hello"), while `fstream` supports both output and input operations but depending on the flags given when opening the file. In your example, the open mode is `ios_base::in | ios_base::out` by default. The default open mode of `ofstream` is `ios_base::out`. Moreover, `ios_base::out` is always set for ofstream objects (even if explicitly not set in argument mode).

Use `ofstream` when `textfile` is for output only, `ifstream` for input only, `fstream` for both input and output. This makes your intention more obvious.

Comment: y ! cite cppreference.com instead

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf cppreference.com is prettier, but google returns me cplusplus.com for `c++ fstream`. What are other advantages of cppreference.com over cplusplus.com?

Comment: @DanqiWang: generally more correct due to better peer-review