# fstream, ofstream difference and good coding style

Tags: c++

I am not aware what exactly is the difference between these two versions.
If you want to only write a file in c++ you can do 2 things.

```
std::fstream(fileNameStr, std::ios::out);
std::ofstream(fileNameStr);
```

There is a question and answer what it does [ofstream what it does and trunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258825/c-fstream-and-ofstream) where it is said `std::ofstream` is for writing only and there can be a problem not creating a file when not using `std::ios::trunc`.
In `std::fstream` `std::ios::trunc` deletes all contents I know, so this can be wrong from what I want.
I tried it in VC14 and gcc-4.9 (x86) and it creates a file which is not existent.

What I want to know, is there anything said in the c++ standard what happens with non existent files, and can I run into problems with ARM gcc or other compilers?

Can I run into trouble using this on different architectures at all?

Comment: First, please only ask one question per question.  Second, you last question is generally off topic as coding styles are mainly Primarily opinion based.

Comment: [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) should explain the differences well. Also: Is your ENTER key broken? Please cleanup that unreadable wall of text.