# Ostream causing issue with file i/o

Tags: c++

I omitted much of my code and much of my original input file just to make it easier and simpler to read, and to focus on one specific problem.

Each time I try and compile this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void readExpression(ostream &fin, double operand1, char oepratr, double operand2);

int main()
{
    double operand1,
           operand2;

    char operatr;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("inp.txt");

    readExpression(fin, operand1, operatr, operand2);

    fin.close();

    return 0;
}

void readExpression(ostream &fin, double operand1, char operatr, double operand2)
{
    cin >> operand1 >> operatr >> operand2;
}
```

This is the input file:

```
2.0 + 2.0
```

I always get the error that I have

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::ostream& {aka std::basic_ostream<char>&}' from expression of type 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}'|
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've been at this for hours and still haven't found a solution, after countless hours of researching. I am fairly new to cpp and only have experience in other language, which is why I am struggling with what seems like an elementary concept. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ostream &fin` should be `istream &fin` and the line `cin >> operand1 >> operatr >> operand2;` should be `fin >> operand1 >> operatr >> operand2;`

Comment: I assume you also want to pass your arguments by reference to `readExpression`, otherwise it's sort of pointless as they will not be changed outside the scope of that function, and if that's your intention they should just be local variables.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have mixed information about streams. You correctly created an `ifstream` object in `main()` that will be binded to a file, but your function signature:

```
void readExpression(ostream &fin, double operand1, char oepratr, double operand2);
```

uses `std::ostream&` - the **output** stream, not the **input** stream. `std::ifstream` inherits from `std::istream`, which is used for *reading from*, not *writing to*. What you want to do, is change it to:

```
void readExpression(istream &fin, double operand1, char oepratr, double operand2);
```

Besides that, your function body is also incorrect. You do not use the argument `fin`, but you are **always** reading from `std::cin`. Thus you need to change the `cin >> ...` to `fin >> ...`. Your complete function would look like:

```
void readExpression(istream &fin, double operand1, char operatr, double operand2)
{
    fin >> operand1 >> operatr >> operand2;
}
```

You might be interested in reading [this question and answers to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258825/c-fstream-and-ofstream).